# Using .replace() to change a string permanently in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Does `.replace()` always need to be declared inside a `print()` statement or can you use it to change a string permanently? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Since strings are "immutable" objects, you can't mutate it at all. It's true for all of it's methods.

`.replace` is also create a new string object for you.

```
s1 = 'hello'
s2 = s1.replace('e', '3')
print(s1, id(s1))
print(s2, id(s2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `.replace()` always inside of `print()`

Like the below example, you can change the `str` with `.replace()` and then print changed `str`

```
myStr = "I love programming"

myStr = myStr.replace("programming", "chicken Nugget")

print(myStr)
```